# According to the business trend of OpenLayers - To which extent OpenLayers supported features will remain free?

Tags: openlayers

I want to gain a very clear replies to the following enquiries:

1. Is there any future intention or business trend for OpenLayers to partially convert one of its free features to be used according to commercial business plan?
2. When I am using OpenLayers as a map provider in my web application that is used for commercial use, is there any pitfalls / obstacles or limitations to the amount of data used or any concerns related to data licensing?
3. Would be there any limitations in the freely used features when it is used in a commercial web application?

Comment: 2. OpenLayers is not a map provider.  Commercial data sources used with OpenLayers usually require an API key from the provider and are subject to terms of use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification, Mike. I have read more to better understand the difference between the web map API and map providers. I have ended up that OpenLayers is a completely free, open-source JavaScript API library for displaying map data on browsers. It can load map data from many data sources either commercial or free.